# Prove that $n\sqrt{n}∈O(n^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, algorithms, notation

How do I go about proving that $$n\sqrt{n}∈O(n^2)$$? I think I get the idea of $O$-Notation, whereby it shows if a function grows faster than or at the same rate compared to another function. The idea seems pretty simple and this question is listed as an example of an $O$ function without an explanation, along with many others. Also what's another simpler example of an $O$ function.

Could you say that $a(n)=n^2+3n+4$, $a(n^2)∈O(n^2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $n$ goes to infinity, $$ \dfrac{n\sqrt{n}}{n^2}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
is absolutely bounded by the constant $1$ (or any constant at all for that matter, since it tends to $0$, but the point is that there *is* such a constant).

In your last example, $a(n)$ is $O(n^2)$, but not $a(n^2)$ if that is really what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{n\sqrt{n}}{n^{2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\leq 1$, so $n\sqrt{n}\in O(n^{2})$. But it is not the case that $a(n^{2})\in O(n^{2})$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)
$$
f\in O(g)\text{ as }x\rightarrow a
$$
whenever
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow a}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|<\infty
$$
in this case since

$$\dfrac{n\sqrt{n}}{n^2}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to0$$

we have that $n\sqrt{n}∈O(n^2)$.